# Combine 2 videos into 1 seamless video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I have 2 videos - a first chunk and a second chunk - from the same project (I had export problems.)

These two chunks have some overlap. But I need to combine these two chunks so that when the first chunk ends at 2 minutes 32 seconds, the second chunk picks up at a specific point seamlessly.

How can I seamlessly combine these two chunks and export it into one video?

Any answer that doesn't see a drop in video quality would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How much overlap do the two streams have? That determines how much leeway you have in picking the most suitable cut point (an I-frame would be best). Is there an audio stream as well? If you end up having to re-encode for the splicing, can you just re-export from the original instead?

Comment: Also, this feels pretty much off-topic for U&L SE (there's nothing OS-specific in your question), but I don't know of a more suitable SE site for video editing.

Comment: I'm aware of https://video.stackexchange.com/ and for this to be on-topic at U&L, you should mention your OS, so that we know what tools you have available.

Comment: Hello, I am on OS Mojave (10.14.6). The first stream is the intro of the video and ends at 2 minutes 32 seconds, the second stream is the entire project (over 1 hour) but it contains a faulty into. So I guess I could just pick it up again at 2 minutes 32 seconds?

Comment: So in actual fact, the second stream needs the first 2 minutes 32 seconds overwritten by the first stream. I'm sorry I didn't word it that clearly before - didn't occur to me.